# C++ : Why redeclare a template's generic data type after one use?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax-error

I was wondering why a template's definition of a generic data type can only be used once.

```
template<class T>
T x;
T y;   // error: identifier 'T' not defined
```

```
template<class T>
T x, y;   // error: expected ';' instead of ','
```

If I make a class, ***T*** can be used as many times as I want within the class definition. If I were to define a member function outside of it, I'm forced to redeclare the type again `template<class T>`. Same for a function's prototype definition. That applies even in the same scope.

```
template<class T>
T x;
template<class T>
T y;   // OK
```

There's an exception though, the code below is considered all good. If I initialize the variables, it suddenly works.

```
template<class T>
T x = 0, y = 0;   // OK
```

*So, why have to redeclare a template's generic data type after one use?* 
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your last declaration works is a bug in whatever compiler you are using. A template declaration can only declare a single entity<sup>[[1]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#5)</sup>. That's just the rules of c++, so you have to have 2 templated declarations for your 2 variable templates.